# Some unsettling technical issue when solving probability expectation problems

Tags: probability, derivatives

I'm suddenly not sure about something I used a few times.

Say I get to the expectation of some descrete random variable with parameter $p$, say $p$ is the probability of success: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp^{k-1}$.

To simplify this, I say $\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp^{k-1}=[\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k]'=(\frac 1 {1-p})'=\frac 1 {(1-p)^2}$.

The derivation is done by taking $p$ as a variable and differentiating with respect to $p$.

But actually, $p$ has a known value, say $p=0.2$. So when I get to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\cdot 0.2^{k-1}$, can I say this equals to $[\sum_{k=0}^\infty 0.2^k]'$ by deriving with respect to the variable 0.2? Sounds strange.

So, if I get to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\cdot 0.2^{k-1}$ I should say "let $p\equiv 0.2$, and now we can take the derivative with respect to $p$"?

How is $0.2$ different than $p$? It is only a change of names...

Comment: It is more about the derivative issue than the probability one. E.g. $f'(0) = \left. \frac {d} {dx} f(x)\right|_{x = 0}$ means after you find out the derivative $f'$, you evaluate the function at $x = 0$; of course you will always get a zero with $ \frac {d} {dx} f(0)$ as $f(0)$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that it doesn't make sense to differentiate with respect to $p$ if $p$ is a fixed constant. However, that notation is pretty standard even if it is a somewhat sloppy shortcut. If you prefer, you could switch to a variable $x$ and say that for any $0<x<1$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k x^{k-1} = \left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\right]'=\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)' = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$
Then evaluating the above expression at $x=p=0.2$ gives you the desired result.

Comment: Sounds a bit artificial, but it is the answer I was expecting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The derivation is correct for all values of $p$.  Yes, it uses the ability to take a derivative with respect to $p$, which works because $\frac 1{1-p}$ is a nice function.  After the general case is solved, you come along and say you are interested in the specific case $p=0.2$, so you substitute that in.